# Making keyboard and mouse operations in a windows service running as a local system?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, remote-desktop, uac

My Question Is How can I make Mouse and Keyboard operations by using win32.dll or other dlls from a service running in LocalSystem? In this way, the IT employee can type the username and password during the remote connection?

Answer (score 1):

A windows service cannot access to the graphical desktop.
so you cannot move the mouse neither send keyboard keys from windows service.
You do not need to access win32.dll with specific code as there exist already classes in C# to do this things.
I might however decouple the functionalities with a standard process to access to the desktop and eventually communicates with windows service inter process technique .
I miss however why you need it as a service if your use case is a co worker who could just directly launch your desktop specific app without needing to worry about win service.
I also miss why you could not use remote acces from MsTeams

Comment: Since mouse and keyboard operations work with full authority in the local system account, uac does not block the screen, but if I run an application in the user account, uac blocks it.

Comment: So you already done it, problem is solved

Comment: No, I still don't know how to do mouse and keyboard operations on the local system. When I use win32 dll, I get an access denied error :(

Comment: You try to move the mouse from a standard winform destkop app ?
paste in the existing code below.